# Dynamic action in HTML form with POST method

Tags: angularjs

My webapp must redirect the user to another website on which I have no control. This website expect to receive a few POST parameters from the user.

Without angular, I would have to redirect the user using a form like this :

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="https://otherwebsite.com/index.php"> 
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="id" VALUE="A1S2D3"> 
  <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="number" VALUE="1234567"> 
  <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="SUBMIT" VALUE="Submit"> 
</FORM>
```

In angular, this would also work, but I want the action url and the value of "number" to come from angular's scope.

Sadly, it doesn't seems to work when I use ng-model or {{var}} in the value/action attributes.

Any idea to redirect the user to the other website with POSTed parameters from the scope?

Comment: Is the post already working properly without using JavaScript?

Comment: If I manually set the action and the value of the input in the html page, it works. I want to have a similar result in an angularjs app with dynamic values. I'm not sure it is possible with angular, but there must be a dirty way of doing it (injecting a form from JS into the DOM and submitting it for example)...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use javascript change the form action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361751/how-to-use-javascript-change-the-form-action)

Comment: As you said I don't think this is possible with just Angular, bu might be doable with pure JS.

Comment: Nicolas, I think this other question is a valid way of doing it, but it is not a duplicate since there might be a way to do it in angular without pure js hacks.

Comment: Answered same question in a similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37408404/2244262

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I have found a simple a way of using it that (kinda uses) Angular.

I have an angular function

```
$scope.setAction= function(){
    document.myForm.action='http://anothersite.com';
};
```

where `myForm` is the name attribute of your form.

```
<form action="http://asamplesite.com" method="POST" name="myForm">
```

See my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/nicolasmoise/f6R9x/

**Note** this kinda goes against the "Angular Way" because in your view, you have no way of seeing that logic, it's kinda hidden inside the controller. However, as it was stated in the question I linked to, Angular doesn't like submitting form the old ways. An alternative could be having the form call a function through `ng-submit` that gets your dynamic url and does the redirecting/reloading (using `$location` maybe). That way might be longer but at least your logic will be more evident in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Use the directive for [ngSubmit](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) which allows you to call a method to submit a form. According to the documentation if the form contains action, data-action, or x-action attributes then it will perform the default form action. Which for a form means sending the request to the server and reloading the current page.

```
  <script>
    function Ctrl($scope) {
      $scope.number = "1234567";
      $scope.id = "A1S2D3";
    }
  </script>

  <form ng-submit ng-controller="Ctrl" data-action="https://otherwebsite.com/index.php">
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="id" ng-model="id">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="number" ng-model="number">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The input binded with ng-model have no value in the  post request and the action is not bindable.

Comment: Yes it's very interesting I was working on testing it and ran into [the following error](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/insecurl?p0=https:%2F%2Fotherwebsite.com%2Findex.php).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with hidden inputs(seems like angular are ignoring them).

I used this solution:

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="number" ng-model="myNumber" hidden>
```