# ng-action does not add action attribute in the form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to have dynamic action attribute in the form. I have a code

```
 <form ng-action="/users/{{user.id}}">
 </form>
```

Angular does replaces `{{user.id}}` with the actual value, but it does not add `action` attribute with the new value. How do i fix this?

I also tried with

```
<form action="/users/{{user.id}}"></form>
```

It does working in Angular `1.2.1`, but not in higher version `(>1.2.1)`

1. JSFiddle with angular version `1.2.1`, http://jsfiddle.net/fizerkhan/s8uCT/5/
2. JSFiddle with angular version `1.2.2`, http://jsfiddle.net/fizerkhan/s8uCT/6/

I also tried with angular version `1.2.4`, `1.2.6`, it does not work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no directive called ng-action in Angular

**[refer Angular DOCS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive)**

```
<form action="{{'/users/' + user.id }}">
```

You need to add above tag for that to work

Comment: Check with this     <form action="{{'/users/' + user.id }}">

Comment: I tried it, but it is working below version 1.2.1. From angular version 1.2.2 and greater, it does not work.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/judet/1/edit i have tried with 1.3 and 1.2.14 the above answer is working fine. Please check your $scope if the value is proper

Comment: Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fizerkhan/s8uCT/3/ which uses angular version 1.2.2 and I also tried with 1.2.3 and greater. It does not work. You can check action url through developer console.

Comment: Great. `action="{{'/users/' + user.id }}"` works, but `action="/users/{{user.id}}"` does not work. Can you update the answer.

Answer (score 8):

For Angular 1.2+, you'll need to trust the URL with SCE.

In the controller, add a dependency on `$sce`.  Then, define the url as below

```
$scope.formUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('/users/' + user.id);
```

Then in the view

```
<form action="{{formUrl}}" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.2, Angular ships with Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE) enabled by default.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to change the action attribute, as the following example:

```
$('#formId').attr('action', '/users/'+$scope.user.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using Angular directives:

JS:

```
app.controller('formCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.customAction = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
}])
.directive('dynamicFormAction', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'dynamicFormAction': '='
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('dynamicFormAction', function (action) {
                el[0].action = action;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST" dynamic-form-action="customAction">
     ...
</form>
```