# Ridding of Concat Error on Image Upload AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angularJs 1.5.5. I have set an image uploaded in html and angularjs that is pure front side. This is what it appears to be:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/file-upload/{{clientId}}">
<input type="file" name="thumbnail">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image">
</form>
```

However, `{{clientId}}` is a parameter, thus brings the Concat error. 
I have tried to structure it like this:

```
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" ng-click="uploadDoc()">
  <input type="file" name="thumbnail">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image">
  </form>
```

Where the function "`uploadDoc()`" is represented here:

```
 $scope.uploadDoc = function() {
    $http.post('/file-upload/'+$scope.clientId)
};
```

However, I do not know how to gain the image this way, thus this results in not being able to capture the image selected. I am a little loss as to how to upload this image (which I am also using backend express for, but I know my code there works just fine) with the parameter of clientId, but without concatenation.

Comment: Have you tried: `action="{{'/file-upload/' + clientId}}"` - stolen from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661299/ng-action-does-not-add-action-attribute-in-the-form

Comment: Yes, I have tried this -- when I go to post, it does not retain the clientId