# How to pass a variable to URL when submit a form in HTML

Tags: html, forms

I have a form in html. What I want is to to redirect to URL /number/(The number input in number field).

How can I make it?

```html
<form action="/number/????" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">  
Number
<input type="text" name="number">  
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Go">  
</form>
```

Comment: Do you actually need the form to submit or do you just need to redirect when someone clicks the submit button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JavaScript to change the form action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361751/how-to-use-javascript-to-change-the-form-action)

Comment: Just to redirect when click submit button and bring the "number" value into the URL.