# Change form action without jQuery, but using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form for submitting comments and one of the tricks I use it to tackle/confuse spambots is to simply change the form action call via jquery. So the original form will, in the HTML source, normally call the mycomment.php file when somebody submits a comment. But with this simple bit of code I can intercept and change that, while replacing mycomment.php with a dummy 0 bytes files:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#commentformid').attr('action', '/mycomment-realfile.php');
});
```

However, I'm not a javascript coder, but I now want to be able to do exactly the same thing, albeit without needing to use the jQuery library. So I need to do the same as above, but without jquery being involved. Ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Javascript to change the form action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5361785/1599011)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it in vanilla js. I hope it's usefull
on `DOMContentLoaded` you reference your `commentformid` element then if the element is there you can proceed to change its `action` attribute

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('commentformid');
    if (form) {
        form.action = '/mycomment-realfile.php';
    }
});
```